# How to get updated records (in terms of position) from server through pagination

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, web-services

How do I code a process in which multiple users each request a group of records from a server and delete those records one at a time ... without conflicting with each other.

For example: Given 500 records in the server. Each of `n` users would request five records and delete them one at a time through a web service.  I currently request server for records with offset and limit from front end

Scenario:

1. User1: fetched 1st 5 records
2. User1: fetched 2nd 5 records
3. User2: fetched 1st 5 records and deleted all (so 6th record is 1st,
   7th is 2nd, ..... 500 is 455)
4. User1: fetching 3rd 5 records(here i am getting records from 11 to 15. Due to User2 deletion of 5 records, 6th record is now at 1st position. So, as per offset and limit fetches the data from 11 to 15
   and updated position for records 6 to 10 is missed here. i.e records
   11 to 15 new positions are 6 to 10).

So, here how can i able to get the next 5 undeleted records from server or how can i give the next 5 un-deleted records to the request)

How to implement this logic?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Thanks for fomatting my post

Answer (score 0):

user needs to remember last visited record and ask for next 5 records before (or after) last visited.

That also implies that you would need some sort of ordering to tell database what is next/previous record.

Comment: Thanks, Last marked record was deleted by some other user and its no more exist in the server. So how can i give next 5 records to the request which not given in the previous request?

Comment: You are sorting records by some COLUMN. Last seen record has certain value in that column. Now, it doesn't metter if this record is present in a database anymore. You will sort recordset by above COLUMN and take next five records that are bigger/smaller that value from "last seen" record. You know the value, because you fetched it to the client (even if client do not see that column).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest (but may be a bit taxing) method is to pass last id of row instead of page number.
And on server side, fetch next 5 records after that id.